# tinymce jquery plugin error tinymce is not a function

Tags: jquery-plugins, tinymce

I'm using [tinymce jquery plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php) and trying to access the api after initializing an instance of tinymce over a textarea.

In this example, I have a hide button, which when clicked on is supposed to hide the tinymce editor, but instead I get an error.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><textarea id="textEditor" class="tinymce" disabled="disabled"></textarea></div>
    <input type ="button" id="hide" value="Hide tinymce">
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

//textEditor
$("#textEditor")
.tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url : 'js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,",
    theme_advanced_resizing : false
})

//... see below ...//

});
```

**Update**: I have 2 versions now, one that works by wrapping the $("#textEditor").tinymce().hide();  line in a click function, and one that gives me tinyMCE not defined with just the line itself.

Works:

```js
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#textEditor").tinymce().hide(); 
})
```

Doesn't work:

```js
    $("#textEditor").tinymce().hide(); //error tinyMCE is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
tinymce.get("textEditor").hide();
```

To verify if you are useing the correct tinymce id can alert all tinymce ids present at your page using

```
for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
   alert(tinymce.editors[i].id);
}
```

EDIT:

This:

```
/** Option Block A error **/    
 // $("#textEditor").tinymce().hide(); //error tinyMCE is not defined
/** Option Block A error **/
```

does not work because it will get called before the tinymce editor is initialized. At this point there is no `tinymce.get("textEditor")`.

Comment: @Thariama those don't work for me; I get the error `tinymce is not defined`, possibly due to jquery selector way of initializing it. It turns out I just missed the $ char in my original question. But another question would be how to access the tinymce instances as you do in the for loop, using the jquery plugin way. Thanks.

Comment: hava look at the tinymce jquery example page: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php . using firebug there is the variable tinymce available. are you sure tiny_mce.js is loaded?

Comment: @Thariama yes it's loaded. I just updated the question with something that puzzles me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you put your example page online so that i and other can have a closer look?

Comment: @Thariama the code is pretty much what I've posted in the question. So replacing `//...see below...//` with the subsequent two chunks of code yield those results respectively.

Comment: use the setup init parameter and use ed.onInit inside of it

Answer (score 1):

I think that the path to your jquery plugin is not correct, because, the $.tinymce() method is provided there. If the file is not to be found, so is this method.

Also you should ensure that the path specified inside the *script_url* field is valid, as the plugin will try to load it on the fly.